# Implement the divisibility-by-7 rule

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, division

To check whether a decimal number is divisible by 7:

> Erase the last digit. Multiply it by 2 and subtract from what is left. If the result is divisible by 7, the original number is divisible by 7.

(also described e.g. [here](https://www.easycalculation.com/divisibility-rule-by-7.php))

This rule is good for manual divisibility check. For example:

> Is 2016 divisible by 7?
>
> Subtract `6*2` from 201; we get 189. Is this divisible by 7? To check it, let's apply the rule again.
>
> Subtract `9*2` from 18; we get 0. Therefore, 2016 is divisible by 7.

In this challenge, you should apply this rule until the divisibility status is *obvious*, that is, the number is not greater than 70 (however, see below for details). Make a function or a full program.

**Input**: a positive integer; your code should support inputs up to 32767 (supporting arbitrary-precision integers is a bonus; see below).

**Output**: an integer (possibly negative), not greater than 70, that is a result of applying the divisibility-by-7 rule zero or more times.

Test cases:

```
Input                   Output      Alternative output

1                       1
10                      10          1
100                     10          1
13                      13          -5
42                      42          0
2016                    0
9                       9
99                      -9
9999                    -3
12345                   3
32767                   28          -14

---------- Values below are only relevant for the bonus

700168844221            70          7
36893488147419103232    32          -1
231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872    8
```

Where two possible outputs are specified, either result is correct: the second one corresponds to applying the rule one more time. It's forbidden to apply the rule on a single-digit number: if you erase the digit, nothing (not 0) is left.

---

**Bonus**: If your algorithm

- Supports arbitrary-precision integers
- [Performs only one pass on the input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm)
- Has space complexity `o(n)` (i.e. less than `O(n)`); and
- Has time complexity `O(n)`,

where `n` is the number of decimal digits:

Subtract 50% from your code's byte count.

**Real bonus**:

In addition, if your algorithm reads the input in normal direction, starting from the most significant digit, subtract 50% once again - your score is 25% of your byte count (it seems possible, but I'm not absolutely sure).

Comment: Can you please clarify how we have to handle 9 < input < 70? Should we apply the rule at least one time? Or can we just print it out, since its lower than 70 and the divisibility status is obvius?

Comment: @DenkerAffe Returning the input as-is is acceptable. I updated the test-case of input=10 to reflect this; that was the idea from the beginning.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use that rule on `1000000000000000000001`.

Comment: But what if your language has `long long`s or some equivalent type built in?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 `long long` in C has fixed width - not enough. Arbirary-width integers are called `bigint` or something like that. Using a built-in bigint type is OK.

Comment: What I was saying was that, in some implementations, it's a 128-bit integer, which is more than big enough for that last test case.

Comment: -1. Not all languages support arbitrary precision.

Comment: @MarchHo All turing complete languages support arbitrary precision.

Comment: @MarchHo - most languages support long enough strings to implement the algorithm without needing to convert the input to an integer type.

Comment: @Labo pretty sure Turing completeness isn't required for a language to be considered valid here. And in any case, the whole point is that a vast majority of languages do not support arbitrary precision, which the question required. I guess the string implementation kind of alleviates this though.

Comment: This would be more interesting if someone found a closed form expression.

Comment: @rr- It looks funny though. (using alternate output : http://imgur.com/yeNSUhr)

Comment: What's the point of the arbitrary precision requirement? It disadvantages languages in which that's difficult to do while providing a boost to most golfing languages which don't need one, and doesn't add anything to the core challenge.

Comment: @RobertFraser I need it so I can properly formalize the "bonus" requirement

Comment: Then why is support for arbitrary precision not a part of the bonus requirement?

Comment: @Dennis No reason... I'll move it there!

Comment: I see you've added a bonus.  What counts as "reading the input in normal direction", and "Performs only one pass on the input"?  Does [my dc answer](/a/73163/39490) qualify for the bonus?  Or does it need to be a digit-by-digit answer?

Comment: @TobySpeight If it divides a number by 10 repeatedly, it does several passes on the input.

Comment: I think I understand the requirement now - it needs to be digit-at-a-time processing, which won't really work with dc or bc.  I've submitted [an answer in C](/a/73576/39490) that reads input as a string and processes digits in order, which I believe claims the 75% discount.

Answer (score 23):

## Golfscript, <s>27</s> 22 bytes

```
{.9>{.10/\10%2*-f}*}:f
```

You can use it this way:

```
1000f
```

### Explanation

```
{.9>{.10/\10%2*-f}*}:f
{                  }:f    # Define block 'f' (similar to a function)
 .                        # Duplicate the first value of the stack
  9>{            }*       # If the value on top of the stack is greater than 9 then the block is executed
     .10/\10%2*-          # Same as nb/10 - (nb%10 * 2) with some stack manipulations '.' to duplicate the top of the stack and '\' to swap the the first and second element of the stack
                f         # Execute block 'f'
```

5 bytes saved thanks to Dennis !

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. This is a good answer, however you could improve it by adding a code breakdown and explanation, like the questions above. To reply to this comment, type `@wizzwizz4` (`@` then my username) at the beginning of (or anywhere in) a comment.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Better ? I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by 'code breakdown' (not native speaker sorry)

Comment: I believe by "code breakdown" he meant an explanation, which you've added. This is a very nice first answer indeed. Welcome to the site!

Comment: You can rewrite the `{...}{}if` part as `{...}*`, which will just apply the code block zero of one times, depending on the value pushed by `>`. Also, we're allowed to perform one more iteration (so replacing `70` with `9` saves a byte), and I don't think you need to pop the block with `;`.

Comment: @Dica, this is a first answer good enough to get 12+ upvotes on a question with only 624 views, and to get praise from two moderators. If you keep this up, you'll soon overtake Dennis!

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, nice improvement ! The problem without `;` is that the block is printed with the answer so the output is no longer valid

Comment: I don't think that matters, and I've done it in many of my CJam/GolfScript answers. This is a *function* that pops an integer from the stack and pushes one in return. You could just as easily call it with `~` for the first time, which would consume the block. -- By the way, this is an *excellent* first answer.

Answer (score 13):

### Haskell, 35 bytes

```
until(<71)(\n->div n 10-2*mod n 10)
```

Usage example: `until(<71)(\n->div n 10-2*mod n 10) 36893488147419103232` -> `32`.

Nothing much to explain, it's a direct implementation of the algorithm.

Answer (score 9):

## Jelly, 11 bytes

```
d⁵Uḅ-2µ>9$¿
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZOKBtVXhuIUtMsK1Pjkkwr8&input=&args=MjMxNTg0MTc4NDc0NjMyMzkwODQ3MTQxOTcwMDE3Mzc1ODE1NzA2NTM5OTY5MzMxMjgxMTI4MDc4OTE1MTY4MDE1ODI2MjU5Mjc5ODcy)

#### How it works

```
d⁵Uḅ-2µ>9$¿  Main link. Input: n

d⁵           Divmod; return [n : 10, n % 10].
  U          Upend; yield [n % 10, n : 10].
   ḅ-2       Convert from base -2 to integer, i.e., yield -2 × (n % 10) + (n : 10).

      µ      Push the previous chain as a link and begin a new, monadic chain.
          ¿  Apply the previous chain while...
       >9$     its return value is greater than 9.
```

Comment: And as always, Jelly wins. Dennis, how much bytes would it take to implement a jelly interpreter in Jelly?

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 38 bytes

```
f=lambda x:f(x/10-x%10*2)if x>70else x
```

[Try it here](https://repl.it/Bmip/3)!

Simple recursive approach. Prints x if its < 70 otherwise applies the divisibility rule and calls itself with the result.

Comment: you don't need the space after the `)`

Comment: @Maltysen True. Copy pasted the wrong one, thanks for the hint!

Comment: The if is too verbose. `f=lambda x:x*(x<70)or f(x/10-x%10*2)`

Comment: @Seeq Nice trick, thanks! This should work in theory, but it reaches the maximum recursion depth with 2016 as input while my version does not. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah, right, didn't consider that. This trick considers `x*(x<70) != 0` to be the end condition. If x gets to 0 - like it does with 2016 - the end condition never happens.

Comment: @Seeq Ah, I get it. Thanks for the trick anyway, might use it in the future :)

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
.W>H9-/ZTyeZQ
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.W%3EH9-%2FZTyeZQ&input=36893488147419103232&test_suite_input=1%0A10%0A100%0A13%0A42%0A2016%0A9%0A99%0A9999%0A12345%0A700168844221%0A36893488147419103232&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.W%3EH9-%2FZTyeZQ&input=36893488147419103232&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A10%0A100%0A13%0A42%0A2016%0A9%0A99%0A9999%0A12345%0A700168844221%0A36893488147419103232&debug=0)

This will print all the alternative answers.

#### Explanation:

```
.W>H9-/ZTyeZQ   
            Q   read a number from input
.W              while
  >H9              the number is greater than 9
                do the following with the number:
      /ZT          divide it by 10
     -             and subtract
         yeZ       2*(number%10)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
f(x)=x>9?f(x÷10-x%10*2):x
```

This is a recursive function that accepts an integer and returns a `BigInt`. If the input is a large number like in the last example, Julia parses it as a `BigInt`, so no manual conversion is necessary.

The approach is just a straightforward implementation of the algorithm. It will produce the alternate outputs. Taking the modulus when dividing by 10 yields the last digit and the quotient from integer division by 10 yields everything but the last digit.

Saved a byte thanks to Dennis!

Comment: We're allowed to perform one more iteration, so replacing `70` with `9` saves a byte.

Comment: @Dennis Good call, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
L?<b70by-/bT*%bT2
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3F%3Cb70by-%2FbT*%25bT2yQ&input=700168844221&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A10%0A100%0A13%0A42%0A2016%0A9%0A99%0A9999%0A12345%0A700168844221%0A36893488147419103232&debug=0)

Same recursive approach as in my [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73093/49110). Defines a lambda `y` which is called like this: `y12345`.
The byte counter in the online interpreter shows 19 bytes because I added the lambda call to it, so you can just try it by hitting the run-button.

### Explanation

```
L?<b70by-/bT*%bT2

L                  # Defines the lambda y with the parameter b
 ?<b70             # if b < 70:
      b            # return b, else:
       -/bT*%bT2   # calculate b/10 - b%10*2 and return it
```

Comment: You have a typo in your explanation, 17 should be 70 :P

Answer (score 4):

### CJam - 19 bytes

Do-while version:

```
r~A*{`)]:~~Y*-_9>}g
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r~A*%7B%60)%5D%3A~~Y*-_9%3E%7Dg&input=231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872) or While version #1:

```
r~{_9>}{`)]:~~Y*-}w
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r~%7B_9%3E%7D%7B%60)%5D%3A~~Y*-%7Dw&input=231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872) or While version #2:

```
r~{_9>}{_A/\A%Y*-}w
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r~%7B_9%3E%7D%7B_A%2F%5CA%25Y*-%7Dw&input=231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872).

```
r~                     | Read and convert input
  A*                   | Multiply by 10 to get around "if" rule
     `                 | Stringify
      )                | Split last character off
       ]               | Convert stack to array
        :~             | Foreach in array convert to value
          ~            | Dump array
           Y*          | Multiply by 2
             -         | Subtract
              _        | Duplicate
               9>      | Greater than 9?
    {            }g    | do-while
```

Answer (score 3):

## GNU dc, <s>20</s> 15 bytes

```
[10~2*-d70<F]sF
```

This defines my first (ever) dc function, `F`.  It takes input on the top of stack, and leaves its output at top of stack.  Example usage:

```
36893488147419103232
lFxp
32
```

Answer (score 3):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 116 bytes

```
WITH v(i)AS(SELECT:1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT TRUNC(i/10)-(i-TRUNC(i,-1))*2 FROM v WHERE i>70)SELECT MIN(i)FROM v;
```

Un-golfed

```
WITH v(i) AS
(
  SELECT :1 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC(i/10)-(i-TRUNC(i,-1))*2 FROM v WHERE i>70
)
SELECT MIN(i) FROM v;
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>157</s> <s>192</s> <s>184</s> <s>167</s> <s>159</s> <s>147</s> 138+5 bytes - 50% = 71.5 bytes

**O(1) space, O(n) time, single-pass!**

```hs
h d=d%mod d 10
d%r=(quot(r-d)10,r)
p![d]=d-p*10
p![d,e]=d#(e-p)
p!(d:e:f)|(b,a)<-quotRem(2*d)10,(q,r)<-h$e-a-p=(b+q)!(r:f)
m#0=m
m#n=n-2*m
(0!)
```

Use as `0![6,1,0,2]` to apply the rule to 2016, i.e. pass it a number in stream form with least significant figure first. In this way, it will pass over the number digit by digit, applying the rule with O(1) space complexity.

The ungolfed code is here:

```hs
import Data.Char

{- sub a b = sub2 0 a b
  where
    sub2 borrow (a:as) (b:bs) = res : sub2 borrow2 as bs
      where
        (borrow2, res) = subDig borrow a b
    sub2 borrow (a:as) [] = sub2 borrow (a:as) (0:[])
    sub2 _ [] _ = [] -}

--subDig :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
subDig borrow a b = subDig2 (a - b - borrow)
  where
    subDig2 d = subDig3 d (d `mod` 10)
    subDig3 d r = ((r-d) `quot` 10, r)

seven ds = seven2 0 ds
seven2 borrow (d:e:f:gs) = seven2 (b + borrow2) (res:f:gs)
  where
    (a, b) = double d
    (borrow2, res) = subDig borrow e a
seven2 borrow (d:e:[]) = finalApp d (e-borrow)
seven2 borrow (d:[]) = d - borrow*10

double d = ((2*d) `mod` 10, (2*d) `quot` 10)

finalApp m 0 = m
finalApp m n = n - 2*m

num2stream :: Int -> [Int]
num2stream = reverse . map digitToInt . show
sev = seven . num2stream
```

The gist of how this works is that it implements a [digit-by-digit subtraction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction#In_America), but takes advantage of the fact that each number to be subtracted is at most 2-digits, and so we can subtract an arbitrary amount of these 1-or-2 digit numbers from the main one (as well as eating the least significant digits).

The subtraction algorithm is O(1) and only stores the current 'borrow' value. I altered this to add in the extra digit (either 0 or 1), and we note that this borrow value is bounded (within the range [-2,2] so we need only 3 bits to store this).

The other values stored in memory are temporary variables representing the current 2-digit number to add, a single look-ahead in the stream, and to apply one step of the subtraction algorithm (i.e. it takes two digits and a borrow value, and returns one digit and a new borrow value).

Finally at the end it processes the last two digits in the stream at once to return a single-digit number rather than a list of digits.

N.B. The `sev` function in the ungolfed version will work on an `Integer`, converting it into the reversed stream form.

Comment: I intended the bonus to be for the normal order of digits. But I never said it, so it's fair to get the bonus for the reversed order, even though it's less fun. Anyway, even the reversed order is harder than I thought, so it's fun enough!

Comment: @anatolyg: Thanks! I'm not sure if it's possible to do a single pass O(1) implementation of the normal order... the rule depends on the least significant figures, so in theory direct application of the rule is impossible except in reversed order. The only other thing I can think of is by finding a mathematically equivalent form - for example `Mod[18 - Quotient[n, 10] - 2*n, 21] - 18 + Quotient[n, 10]` works empirically for n between 10 and 99, but gets more complicated the more digits n has...

Comment: Hmm I thought about it and it seemed there might be a way by keeping the front 2 digits and applying each subsequent digit, but multiplying by (-2)^n to take account of it 'filtering through'... as far as I can tell though there's no way to make this work without keeping all the digits in memory and sacrificing the O(1)'ness or even o(n)'ness... I think the normal order is definitely impossible :(

Comment: I'm afraid you have to count the bytes of the initial `0` when calling `!`, too, e.g. as a section `(0!)` (+ a newline), i.e. +5 bytes. On the other side you can shorten the first to pattern matches of `!` to `p![d]=` and `p![d,e]=`. Also, use  pattern guards instead of the `let`: `p!(d:e:f)|(b,a)<-quotRem(2*d)10,(q,r)<-h$e-a-p=(b+q)!(r:f)`.

Comment: @nimi: thanks! I'm a bit confused about "(0!)\n" though (I'm new to Haskell and CodeGolf!) -- can't I just use "0!<input>" for the invocation instead of using a section?

Comment: @nitrous: Oh I ment `(0!)` on a line of it's own. `(0!)` is the function you give as your answer. The `0` is required, but has nothing to do with the input, so you cannot outsource it to the caller. Of course you could also use `f x=0!x`, but this is longer.

Comment: @nimi: Ah I see, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```
If[#>70,#0[{1,-2}.{⌊#/10⌋,#~Mod~10}],#]&
```

Simple recursive approach. Could probably be golfed further.

Comment: `#0[{1,-2}.QuotientRemainder[#,10]]` saves a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 43 bytes

```
x=scan();while(x>70)x=floor(x/10)-x%%10*2;x
```

Explanation:

```
x=scan()                                      # Takes input as a double
        ;                                     # Next line
         while(x>70)                          # While-loop that runs as long x > 70
                      floor(x/10)             # Divide x by 10 and round that down
                                 -x%%10*2     # Substract twice the last integer
                    x=                        # Update x
                                         ;    # Next line once x <= 70
                                          x   # Print x
```

Sample runs:

```
> x=scan();while(x>70)x=floor(x/10)-x%%10*2;x
1: 9999
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] -3

> x=scan();while(x>70)x=floor(x/10)-x%%10*2;x
1: 32767
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 28
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 56 bytes - 75% = 14

Although this doesn't give the exact same numbers as the test cases, it satisfies the spirit of the question (and arguably more).  It correctly identifies exact multiples of 7, and gives the exact remainder for other numbers (since it doesn't ever use negative numbers).

```c
n;f(char*c){for(n=0;*c;)n-=n>6?7:'0'-n-n-*c++;return n;}
```

There is no multiplication or division in the algorithm, only addition and subtraction, and digits are processed in a single pass from left to right.  It works as follows, starting with 0 in the accumulator:

1. Subtract 7 if necessary, and again if still necessary
2. Multiply the running total by three, and add the next digit

The "multiply by three" step is written as `n-=-n-n` to save a byte and to avoid the multiply operator.

When we hit the end, we don't subtract sevens, so the result will be in the range 0-24; if you want a strict modulus (0-7), substitute `*c` with `*c||n>6` in the `for` loop condition.

It qualifies for the enhanced bonus, because it

- supports arbitrary-precision integers
- performs only one pass on the input, in left-to-right order
- has space complexity O(1)
- has time complexity O(n).

### Test program and results

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    while (*++argv)
        printf("%s -> %d\n", *argv, f(*argv));
    return 0;
}
```

```
540 -> 15
541 -> 16
542 -> 17
543 -> 18
544 -> 19
545 -> 20
546 -> 21
547 -> 22
548 -> 23
549 -> 24
550 -> 18
99 -> 15
999 -> 12
12345 -> 11
32767 -> 7
700168844221 -> 7
36893488147419103232 -> 11
231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872 -> 11
```

### Alternative version

Here's one that recurses (you'll want to enable compiler optimizations to do tail-call transformation or you may overflow your stack; I used `gcc -std=c89 -O3`):

```c
f(c,n)char*c;{return n>6?f(c,n-7):*c?f(c+1,n+n+n+*c-'0'):n;}
```

Call it with '0' as the second argument.

Both versions calculate the remainder-modulo-seven of a 60,000 digit number in under 50 milliseconds on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the bonus - it makes a real change for C to end up so competitive!  Currently beaten only by [Jelly](/a/73127) (11) and [Pyth](/a/73101) (13).  :-)

Answer (score 1):

### <del>JavaScript ES6, 38 bytes</del>

```
a=i=>i>70?a(Math.floor(i/10)-i%10*2):i
```

Fails with `36893488147419103232` and using `~~(1/10)` will also fail for `700168844221`

Test:

```js
a=i=>i>70?a(Math.floor(i/10)-i%10*2):i
O.textContent = O.textContent.replace(/(-?\d+) +(-?\d+)/g, (_,i,o) =>
  _+": "+(a(+i)==o?"OK":"Fail")
);
```

```html
<pre id=O>1                       1
10                      10
100                     10
13                      13
42                      42
2016                    0
9                       9
99                      -9
9999                    -3
12345                   3
700168844221            70
36893488147419103232    32</pre>
```

Comment: I get two `Fail`s... 70 and 32

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Yea me to, I'm still wondering why...

Comment: Because JavaScript's number type doesn't handle the last case, at least.

Comment: `f=n=>n>70?f((n-n%10*21)/10):n` is a shorter version but still only works for up to `2**56`.

Comment: @Neil see my answer for arbitrary precision, and please feel free to golf, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
#//.a_/;a>70:>⌊a/10⌋-2a~Mod~10&
```

**Test case**

```
%[9999]
(* -3 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>140</s> 142 bytes

```
f=s=>s>9?eval("t=s.replace(/.$/,'-$&*2');for(i=-1;0>(n=eval(u=t[c='slice'](i-4)))&&u!=t;i--);n<0?n:f(t[c](0,i-4)+('0'.repeat(-i)+n)[c](i))"):s
```

This is true arbitrary-precision math, even works on the largest test-case.

This function recursively removes the last digit from the string, then subtracts 2 * the last digit from the remaining numerical string by iteratively incrementing the amount of digits to apply to the minuend until the difference is positive. Then it appends that difference to the end of the string with appropriately padded `0`s and calls itself recursively until its numerical value is less than or equal to `9`.

- Golfed 7 bytes thanks to @Neil (yes I know I gained 2 bytes but I fixed a few bugs that caused the function to freeze or return wrong output for some cases).

```js
f=s=>s>9?eval("t=s.replace(/.$/,'-$&*2');for(i=-1;0>(n=eval(u=t[c='slice'](i-4)))&&u!=t;i--);n<0?n:f(t[c](0,i-4)+('0'.repeat(-i)+n)[c](i))"):s;[['1',1],['10',1],['100',1],['13',-5],['42',0],['2016',0],['9',9],['99',-9],['9999',-3],['12345',3],['700168844221',7],['36893488147419103232',-1],['231584178474632390847141970017375815706539969331281128078915168015826259279872',8]].map(a=>document.write(`<pre>${f(a[0])==a[1]?'PASS':'FAIL'} ${a[0]}=>${a[1]}</pre>`))
```

Comment: Nice, but it might not work on `1000000000000000000001`.

Comment: Try `s.replace(/.$/,'-$&*2')`. I don't have any obvious ideas for the rest though sorry.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

Had to use `bigint`for the last test case. (It returns 20 without)

```
use bigint;$_=<>;while($_>9){$_-=2*chop;}print
```

Not really sure it's a candidate for the bonus, so I didn't take it into account. (I think it does, but I'm not really accustomed to the concepts)

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/zd6hCN)

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 108 bytes

```
f=(s,n=0)=>s>1e9?f(s.slice(0,-1),((1+s.slice(-1)-n%10)%10*21+n-s.slice(-1))/10):s>9?f(((s-=n)-s%10*21)/10):s
```

Works for 2²⁵⁷ and 1000000000000000000001, but could use further golfing.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oops, oversight when reformatting for the submission.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>368</s> 360 bytes

[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFsoWyh7fSldPCgoKSk-KV0oPD4pKXsoe30oKSk8Pn17fTw-e317fTw-KCh7fSkpe3t9e308Pig8KCgpKT4pfXt9KHt9PD4pe3t9KCh7fSkpKDwoKCgpKCkoKSgpKCkpe308Pik-KTw-eyh7fVsoKV0pPD4oKHt9KClbKHt9KV0pKXt7fSg8KHt9KHt9KSk-KX17fTw-fXt9PD4oWyhbKFsoKHt9PHt9Pjw-KTwoW3t9XXt9KSg8KCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKXt9KDw-KSk-KTw-eyh7fVsoKV0pPD4oKHt9KClbKHt9PCh7fSgpKT4pXSkpe3t9KDwoe30oe308KHt9WygpXSk-KSk-KX17fTw-fXt9PD57fXt9KHt9PD4pPil7fV17fSldPCgoKSk-KSg8PildKXsoe30oKSk8Pn17fTw-e317fTw-KCh7fSkpe3t9e308Pig8KCgpKT4pfXt9KHt9PD4pfXt9&input=MjAxNg)

```
([([({})]<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}<>{}{}<>(({})){{}{}<>(<(())>)}{}({}<>){{}(({}))(<((()()()()()){}<>)>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}()[({})])){{}(<({}({}))>)}{}<>}{}<>([([([(({}<{}><>)<([{}]{})(<((()()()()()){}(<>))>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}()[({}<({}())>)])){{}(<({}({}<({}[()])>))>)}{}<>}{}<>{}{}({}<>)>){}]{})]<(())>)(<>)]){({}())<>}{}<>{}{}<>(({})){{}{}<>(<(())>)}{}({}<>)}{}
```

### Explanation

To start off all of the code is in a loop that runs until the top of the stack is less than zero:

```
([([({})]<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}<>{}{}<>(({})){{}{}<>(<(())>)}{}({}<>)
{{}
 ...
 ([([({})]<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}<>{}{}<>(({})){{}{}<>(<(())>)}{}({}<>)
}{}
```

Inside of the loop we run the divisible by seven algorithm:

Duplicate the top of the stack

```
(({}))
```

Take the mod 10 of the top of the stack (last digit)

```
(<((()()()()()){}<>)>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}()[({})])){{}(<({}({}))>)}{}<>}{}<>({}<{}><>)
```

This is a bit of a mess but it does the rest of the algorithm I might explain it later but I don't entirely remember how it works:

```
([(({})<([{}]{})(<((()()()()()){}(<>))>)<>{({}[()])<>(({}()[({}<({}())>)])){{}(<({}({}<({}[()])>))>)}{}<>}{}<>{}{}({}<>)>){}]{})
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>111</s> 104 bytes

```
int d(int n){var s=""+n;return n<71?n:d(int.Parse(s.Remove(s.Length-1))-int.Parse(""+s[s.Length-1])*2);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 50 bytes

```
for($n=$argv[1];$n>9;)$n=$n/10|0-2*($n%10);echo$n;
```

uses alternative output; works up to `PHP_INT_MAX`

---

string version, works for any (positive) number (64 bytes):

```
for($n=$argv[1];$n>9;)$n=substr($n,0,-1)-2*substr($n,-1);echo$n;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 133 bytes

```
int d(int n){String s=""+n;return n<71?n:d(Integer.parseInt(s.replaceFirst(".$",""))-Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(s.length()-1))*2);}
```

I hate how verbose `Integer.parseInt` is. Ungolfed:

```
static int div(int n) {
    if (n <= 70) {
        return n;
    } else {
        String num = ("" + n);
        int last = Integer.parseInt("" + num.charAt(num.length() - 1));
        int k = Integer.parseInt(num.replaceFirst(".$", "")) - last * 2;
        return div(k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
Ω≤70§-ȯD→d÷10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///OqeKJpDcwwqctyK9E4oaSZMO3MTD///8yMDE2)

Tied with Pyth, using a modified method.

### Explanation

```
Ω≤70§-ȯD→d÷10
Ω≤70          until the number is ≤ 70,
    §-        subtract
        →d    the last digit
      ȯD      doubled
          ÷10 from the number floor divided by 10
```